# What is the DDL cache, and what is it used for?

Tags: database, ddl

I never found any resource what the DDL cache is used for, and what kind of data it contains.
Also it always worked for me, so I had no need to look into this yet.

Comment: it is mentioned here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html#config-cli-subcommands-cache-clean-over